# How to find and remove file by using glob function in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, regex

I want to search a file which has a dot in his name. For example .34234fdf.ico. How to create a regular expression which find for me all files which has dot in the first place in file name and with icon extension ? This is my code:

```
<?php

    $filepath = recursiveScan('/public_html');

    function recursiveScan($dir) {
        $tree = glob(rtrim($dir, '/') . '/.*');
        if (is_array($tree)) {
            foreach($tree as $file) {
                if (is_dir($file)) {
                    //echo $file . '<br/>';
                    recursiveScan($file);
                } elseif (is_file($file)) {
                 if (preg_match(".\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d.ico", $file )) {
                      echo $file . '<br/>';
                       //unlink($file);
                   }           
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `$files = glob('.*.ico');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex would be: `^\..+\.ico`

Yours is not working because `.` represents every character. `\.` matches a "dot"

Comment: Tip: place your `\.` inside single ticks `, so people can actually see it, right now it's just "."

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the dot is always a first character you can use a regex like this:

```
^\..+\.ico
```